# convert a class component to hooks and pass methods to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to convert the `class component` below to a  `function component with hooks` and so far I been unsuccessful.

I cant see any error on the page nor terminal on the page but my goal is to see the form on the page but there is no form showing at the moment.

## class component

```
# PARENT

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo';
import AllInfo from './AllInfo';

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,

        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',

    }

    handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({[input]: e.target.value});
    }

    showSteps = () => {
        const {step, firstName, lastName } = this.state;

        if(step === 1)
            return (
                <PersonalInfo
                        handleChange = {this.handleChange}
                        nextStep = {this.nextStep}
                        firstName = {firstName}
                        lastName = {lastName}
                />);
        if(step === 3)
            return (
                <AllInfo
                        firstName = {firstName}
                lastName = {lastName}
    }


    render() {
        const {step} = this.state;
        return(
            <>
                <h2>Step {step} of 3.</h2>
                {this.showSteps()}
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;



# CHILD

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PersonalInfo extends Component {
    render() {
        const { handleChange, firstName, lastName } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Enter your personal information</h2>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="firstName"
                        placeholder="First name"
                        value = {firstName}
                        onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
                    />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="lastName"
                        placeholder="Last name"
                        value = {lastName}
                        onChange={handleChange('lastName')}
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PersonalInfo;
```

## Functional component

```
# PARENT

import React, { useState } from "react";
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo';

type Props = {
  state: Object,
};

const MultiSteps = (props: Props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    step: 1,
    firstName: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setState({...state, [input]: e.target.value});
  }

  const showSteps = () => {
    if (state && state.step === 1)
      return (
        <PersonalInfo
          handleChange = {handleChange}
          firstName = {state.firstName}
        />);

    if (state && state.step === 2)
      return (
        <AllInfo
          firstName = {state.firstName}
        />);
  }

  return(
        <>
        <h2>Step {state.step} of 3.</h2>
        Hello - {showSteps()}
        </>
  );
}

export default MultiSteps;



# CHILD

import React from "react";

const PersonalInfo = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Enter personal information</h2>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="First name"
          value={props.firstName}
          onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PersonalInfo;
```

Currently there is no error on the page nor the terminal but i am not able to see any form on the page.

New Error below

```
ReferenceError: handleChange is not defined

  12 |     placeholder: "First name" // value={firstName}
  13 |     ,
  14 |     value: "Lorenzo",
> 15 |     onChange: handleChange('firstName')
  16 |   })));
  17 | };
  18 |
```

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: Whats the actual problem here? Do you get an exception?

Comment: You have `[e.input]` that's what may be the cause?

Comment: @mleister i dont see the form at all on the page.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar i recently edited that line to `[e.input]`and I just removed it again. so `[input]` is not the solution. I still cant see any form on the page.

Comment: @mleister i have updated the post with the current error message

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar  i have updated the post with the current error message

Comment: Just an advice, is always better to separe state with hooks, like: `const [step, setStep] = useState(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating a new const value named state inside your function.

```
const { state } = props;
```

If you just remove this line from your function, the "state" word would now make reference to your state const defined via useState(), instead of your newly created const, that is referencing props.state (that is undefined and causes the invalid acesses and makes the form doesn't show up)

The step value should however be accessed directly from the state variable defined in your component (not props.state)

---

Old answer, kept if anyone find this with the same message

Change from

```
if (state.step === 1)
```

to

```
if(state && state.step == 1)
```

should make the error message stop.

The error happens because state is undefined and you are trying to acces a field of it. On the class example it dont happen because you are using an object destructor to acces the step value, so it has no unsafe accesses.

Comment: Your answer fixed it thank you. Do you know why i am unable to see the form on the page thought? there is no error neither on the screen nor the terminal I can see everything else on the page but the form i need from `PersonalInfo`

Comment: Can you check the values of the state prop? Just put a console.log(props.state) right before the first if statement of the showSteps function

Comment: I think i got i

Comment: Just remove the line
 const { state } = props;

Comment: Remove that line from your showSteps function, i'm gonna explain it better on the answer

Comment: again you are right, it solved that problem. I just updated the post with a new error above, on the `child` component now. do you have an idea what to replace that line to ?

Comment: Change from onChange={handleChange('firstName')} to onChange={props.handleChange('firstName')}

Comment: i tried that already just now `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`, this is the error i get

Comment: replace to onChange={props.handleChange}